# How to convert somewhat arbitrary strings to valid human-readable identifiers?

Tags: python, unicode, nlp, naming-conventions, naming

I have long lists of human-readable strings, some of which contain a few non-ASCII and even non-Latin characters.

```
'Count €'  
'Contains äüöß'
'Y tu mamá también.'
'что'
```

But a service I use requires names to consist of only `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `.`, `_`,  (space).

What is a concise way to convert them to uniquish names valid under those requirements?

We want to preserve human-readability as much as possible. For example, ideally do not change `.` to `full stop`, and do not change `&` to `u38`.  And we cannot simply drop invalid characters or diacritics.  For example:

```
'Count euro symbol'
'Contains a with umlaut u with umlaut o with umlaut sharp s'
'Y tu mama_ tambie_n.'
'cyrillic small letter che ...'
```

Here are the constraints:
- must be Python (2 and 3)
- must not require installing a package
- must preserve uniquishness (it's fine if there are edge cases where it does not)
- must be concise

(Note: `'Y tu mama tambien.'` would not be acceptable given the likelihood of breaking the uniquishness constraint.)

There are some parallels to turning arbitrary strings into valid class names or identifiers.

Answer (score 3):

Googling "python character names" brings up the `unicodedata` module.  So one place to start is something like

```
import string
import unicodedata

ALLOWED = set(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '. _')
sentences = ['Count €', 'Contains äüöß', 'Y tu mamá también.', 'что']

def encode(s):
    return ''.join([unicodedata.name(c).replace(" ","_")+"_"
                   if c not in ALLOWED else c for c in s])

for s in sentences:
    print(s)
    print(encode(s))
```

which gives me

```
Count €
Count EURO_SIGN_
Contains äüöß
Contains LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_A_WITH_DIAERESIS_LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_U_WITH_DIAERESIS_LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_O_WITH_DIAERESIS_LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_SHARP_S_
Y tu mamá también.
Y tu mamLATIN_SMALL_LETTER_A_WITH_ACUTE_ tambiLATIN_SMALL_LETTER_E_WITH_ACUTE_n.
что
CYRILLIC_SMALL_LETTER_CHE_CYRILLIC_SMALL_LETTER_TE_CYRILLIC_SMALL_LETTER_O_
```

With just a bit more work (choosing an appropriate delimiter for an escape) you could guarantee that this can be round-tripped perfectly, but that's left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks much.  I currently have something similar to this likewise using `unicode.name`, but your formulation is cleaner and more concise.  I am still holding out hope for a one-liner.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer: that's silly.  We're developers (presumably), not professional code-golfers.  If anything, the above code is too **short**: it doesn't have documentation, it doesn't round-trip, and so on.  I'd reject the code I presented in a code review and have a pointed conversation with whoever committed it!

Comment: I'm not looking to obfuscate it, but maybe there is a clever way to do it cleanly or an existing lib.  We'll see.

Comment: By the way, `unicodedata.name(c)` unfortunately needs to be wrapped in a `try`/`except`.  (I handle it with `'ord' + str(ord(c))'`.)

Comment: This code doesn't satisfy the uniqueness requirement. `encode(u'John EURO_SIGN_') == encode(u'John €')`

Comment: @Robᵩ: as I said in the last sentence, "with just a bit more work [...] you could guarantee that this can be round-tripped perfectly [that is, you'd have a bijection], but that's left as an exercise for a reader".

Comment: True, but round-trip and uniqueness aren't the same thing. My objection was for uniqueness.

Comment: That is also true, but if you're bijective, you're automatically injective.